# How to return values after boolean in multidemensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Im trying to filter a multidimensional array to return only the indexes after a boolean in this array.

The first key in this array needs to stay in the array like "Tafelblad model" and "Uitstraling"
And the optional values after the booleans

```
["Tafelblad model", true, "Rechthoekig", "Vierkant", "Ovaal / Rond / Overig"],
["Uitstraling", "Licht robuust", "Midden robuust", true, "Zwaar robuust", "Weinig", "Midden (standaard)", true, "Veel oneffenheden en scheuren"]`
```

The new array would be like

```
["Tafelblad model", "Rechthoekig"],
["Uitstraling", "Zwaar robuust", "Veel oneffenheden en scheuren"]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map()` and `filter()`

```js
let arrays = [
  ["Tafelblad model", true, "Rechthoekig", "Vierkant", "Ovaal / Rond / Overig"],
  ["Uitstraling", "Licht robuust", "Midden robuust", true, "Zwaar robuust", "Weinig", "Midden (standaard)", true, "Veel oneffenheden en scheuren"]
]

let result = arrays.map(arr => {
  return arr.filter((v, i) => typeof arr[i - 1] === "boolean" || i == 0);
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, guys! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

You can close over a flag that you set to keep the next entry you see:

```
let flag = true; // We want the first one
const newArray = array.filter(entry => {
    const keep = flag;
    flag = typeof entry === "boolean";
    return keep;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
function example(array) {
    let flag = true; // We want the first one
    const newArray = array.filter(entry => {
        const keep = flag;
        flag = typeof entry === "boolean";
        return keep;
    });
    console.log(newArray);
}

example(["Tafelblad model", true, "Rechthoekig", "Vierkant", "Ovaal / Rond / Overig"]);

example(["Uitstraling", "Licht robuust", "Midden robuust", true, "Zwaar robuust", "Weinig", "Midden (standaard)", true, "Veel oneffenheden en scheuren"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.filter(..)` function for that, here is an example:

```js
let arr1 = ["Tafelblad model", true, "Rechthoekig", "Vierkant", "Ovaal / Rond / Overig"];
let arr2 = ["Uitstraling", "Licht robuust", "Midden robuust", true, "Zwaar robuust", "Weinig", "Midden (standaard)", true, "Veel oneffenheden en scheuren"];

const filterFn = (value, index, arr) => {
  return index === 0 || arr[index - 1] === true;
};

arr1 = arr1.filter(filterFn);
arr2 = arr2.filter(filterFn);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

The callback function passed to `.filter(..)` receives the value at the current iteration, the current iteration's index and the original array as parameters. The conditions in the `filterFn` function check if the iteration's index is `0` (the value is the first value in the array) or the previous item is strict equal to `true`